# data validation not rejecting fill down/ incremented cells

Tags: google-sheets

Consider this example where data validation is setup as follows:
[image]

Users of my sheet (who can't be trusted, thus the data validation) have been typing "A1" once & auto filling down w/ the aim of pasting "A1" as many times as needed. What actually happens is auto-increment creates "A2", "A3", ... which aren't being rejected. Is there a way to make it so?

I'm aware that the real solution is for users to correctly duplicate "A1", but I must re-emphasize they can't be trusted.

Comment: Hey there @atloo1, I am not sure I understand what is it that you are trying to do because a data validation with a specific list of items, when the `Reject input` is checked, it **will** indeed reject any inputs. Have you used the appropriate range for the data validation?

Comment: @ale13 Can you not reproduce the example on your end?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is why I am asking for more details - especially about the range for which you selected the data validation and also what are you trying to achieve. @atloo1

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Sorry, this is long overdue: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z0BCbtR8C9uGQMCdzAGMDYX0e5Xiq1ZGwie0Ov64RRo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @ale13 were you notified of my last reply?